# How to render text from javascript object in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array containing two objects:

```
var questions = [{question: "Is the sky blue?", choices: ["Yes", "No"], correctAnswer:0},{question: "Is water wet?", choices: ["Yes", "No"], correctAnswer:0}]
```

I have some javascript to make the questions render on the screen with HTML:

```
<script>
 function askQuestion(x){
  var questiontest = document.getElementById('question');
  questiontest.innerHTML = x.question;
 }

 function loop(){ 
  for(i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
  askQuestion(questions[i]);
  }
 }

 left some stuff out here, not that relevant to question

 addEventListener('load',loop);
</script>
```

My HTML looks like this, displays the current question but not the text of the choices found in the `questions` object:

```
<label for="choice" id="question"></label>
<br><input type="radio" id="choice_1" name="choice" value="1"></input>
<br><input type="radio" id="choice_2" name="choice" value="2"></input>
```

Using this code I can render the question and then two radio buttons i.e. without the text of the choices. Is there anyway that I can render the text of the choices from the `questions` object next to the radion buttons? or do I have to do something stupid like this to make it render correctly?

```
<br><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1"><p id="choice_1"></p></input>
```

I'm trying to do it with vanilla javascript at the moment and will research doing in with jQuery shortly.

Thanks any help appreciated!

Comment: A label will be rendered next to the input element if grouped correctly `<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" />This is the text next to the radio button</label>`

Comment: The problem is that the text needs to be dynamic i.e. I could put `<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" />Is the sky blue?</label>` but then when the second question is found by the loop function that text will remain... unless I am mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-structure your *HTML* so you can label the inputs individually, then it becomes easy

*HTML*

```html
<form id="qform" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend id="l0"></legend>
        <label id="l1" for="c1"></label>
        <input id="c1" type="radio" name="choice" value="1" />
        <br />
        <label id="l2" for="c2"></label>
        <input id="c2" type="radio" name="choice" value="2" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

*JavaScript*

```js
function questionFactory() {
    var i = 0,
        l0 = document.getElementById('l0'),
        l1 = document.getElementById('l1'),
        l2 = document.getElementById('l2');
    return function askQuestion() {
        if (i >= questions.length) return false;
        l0.textContent = questions[i].question;
        l1.selected = false;
        l1.textContent = questions[i].choices[0];
        l2.selected = false;
        l2.textContent = questions[i].choices[1];
        ++i;
        return true;
    }
}
var ask = questionFactory();
ask(); // asks q1, returns true
ask(); // asks q2, returns true
ask(); // returns false, there were no more questions to ask
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JSGFL/1/)